# Capistrano first deploy error with PG migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano

The application works well in local. To be used, I have to seed it first.

Trying to deploy, I got the following:

```
 INFO [b83023c5] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@51.254.129.78
 DEBUG [b83023c5] Command: cd /home/deploy/guialocal/releases/20180714191701 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
 DEBUG [b83023c5]   rake aborted!
 DEBUG [b83023c5]   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "configs" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "configs".* FROM "configs" ORDER BY "configs"."id" A...
                                 ^
: SELECT  "configs".* FROM "configs" ORDER BY "configs"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
 DEBUG [b83023c5]   /home/deploy/guialocal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `prepare'
```

The config table is a table with just 1 record that I use via initializers to load info in global vars that I use in each VPS deployed instances and across all the application.

**db/migrate/20180531033550_create_configs.rb**

```
class CreateConfigs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :configs do |t|
      t.integer :city

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**db/seeds.rb**

```
Config.create!(
  city: "city_name"
)
```

**config/initializers/instance_configs.rb**

```
$current_city = Config.try(:first).try(:city)
```

Comment: You may need to tweak your deploy script to run the migrations before `rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in initializers, you cannot do BD operations (Is not yet workable). In mi case, I removed the assignation used a helper_method mo get the info once everything in fully loaded.